# How can I print full cl.exe path in my vcxproj file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

For a custom build target, I would like to have full path with correct version of cl.exe which is being called in ClCompile target.

From [retrieve path to cl.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739853/how-to-retrieve-the-path-to-cl-exe), I get it is `%VCINSTALLDIR%\bin\x86\Hostx86\cl.exe` or `%VCINSTALLDIR%\bin\x64\Hostx64\cl.exe`, But I do not want to write program for x84 vs x64 logic.

In VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.Targets, I find that there is property ToolExe and ToolPath are being set to $(CLToolExe) and $(CLToolPath).

Overriding these properties also changed the path to compiler successfully for me, so it's correct that these are the properties names. [Override Compiler in MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835043/how-to-override-compile-command-of-visual-studio-2017-community)

But when I try printing %(CL.ToolPath) or $(CLToolPath) in my custom target exec class, it prints nothing. I also looked in Visual Studio and couldn't find where it was being set.

Is there a variable which can provide cl.exe full path or is there any way I can print property ToolPath of CL Task in my custom target?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** If you already uses the `$(CLToolExe)` and `$(CLToolPath)` to set your new `cl.exe` and then want to get the full path of it, you should use this `$(CLToolPath)$(CLToolExe)` to get the new value rather than `%(CL.ToolPath)`(there is no such way like this).

This is my test result:

**Actually**, you can overwrite these properties directly under your `xxx.csporj` file rather than in `Microsoft.CppCommon.Targets` file and when you build your project, it will use the new `cl.exe`.

[image: CLToolExe]

**Then**, I use a custom target to get the value:

```
<Target Name="test123" AfterTargets="ClCompile">
        <Exec Command="$(CLToolPath)$(CLToolExe)" />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="$(CLToolPath)$(CLToolExe)"></Message>
</Target>
```

[image]

**2)** If you did not change to the new value and use the default `cl.exe` without any changes, you should use `$(ClCompilerPath)` to get the default value.

```
 <Target Name="test123" AfterTargets="ClCompile">       
       <Message Importance="high" Text="$(ClCompilerPath)"></Message>
 </Target>
```

[image]

**Note**: `$(ClCompilerPath)` cannot get the new value of `$(CLToolPath)$(CLToolExe)` since they are not related and can only get the default value.

Comment: $(ClCompilerPath) prints nothing for me. I tried this target 123 exactly.

Comment: What is your project type? Did you miss some system `targets` or `props` file in the `xxx.vcxproj` file? Could you please share your `xxx.vcxproj` file with us? The normal c++ projects are compiled by cl.exe and the property `ClCompilerPath` is the system property which defines that the full path of `cl.exe`. And it should not be empty. Besides, if you create a new default c++ project, does it print the property 
 `ClCompilerPath`?

Comment: @MrQian at least in VS2022 the rules are pretty clear and `ClCompilerPath` only ever gets populated when invoking code analysis. So it's nothing that would work generally ...